# Putting a symbol above vertical line in table.

Tags: tables

I wish to create a table looking as the picture attached below (sorry, but the upload picture is not horizontally), where above the vertical lines we can put a symbol. Thanks! 
[image: the table I want to create]

Comment: Can one assume the cell contents are of fixed width, or may the cell contents vary in width?

Comment: Yes, one can assume that the cell contents are of fixed width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\tabsymbol}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c@{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}{}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.8cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{C|C|C|C|C|}
\tabsymbol{0}&\tabsymbol{1}&\tabsymbol{2}&\tabsymbol{3}&\tabsymbol{4}\\
 & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
 &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
 &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, I use a `\readTABstack` to analyze the data in the `tabular` so that the column widths may be extracted and utilized.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\data{
  This & is & a & test & of & something\\
  \hline%
  &and&not&easy&at&that\\
  \hline
}

\setstackEOL{\\
\hline}% MUST MIMIC the \\ \hline format of \data

\expandafter\readTABstack\expandafter{\data&&&&&}% ENOUGH & ADDED FOR TOTAL COLUMNS

\newcommand\skipcolumn[2]{%
  \unskip\hspace{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep+\TABwd{#1}}\makebox[0pt]{#2}\ignorespaces}

\stackunder{%
  \skipcolumn{1}{A}\skipcolumn{2}{B}\skipcolumn{3}{C}
  \skipcolumn{4}{D}\skipcolumn{5}{E}\skipcolumn{6}{F}
}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \data
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To understand what is happening from the logic point of view, I must build a TABstack of the same column dimensions as the `tabular`.  If I can do that, `tabstackengine` remembers the column dimensions of the raw data in `\TABwd` which can be later used by the method above.  Below, I show the equivalent TABstack build of the `tabular` data.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\data{
  This & is & a & test & of & something\\\hline
  &and&not&easy&at&that\\\hline
}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\data
\end{tabular}
is a tabular

\setstacktabbedgap{2\tabcolsep}
\setstackEOL{\\\hline}

\rule[-3ex]{\fboxrule}{4ex}%
\hspace{\dimexpr\tabcolsep-\fboxrule}%
\expandafter\tabbedLongunderstack\expandafter{\data&&&&&}%
\hspace{\dimexpr\tabcolsep-\fboxrule}%
\rule[-3ex]{\fboxrule}{4ex}
is a TABstack
\end{document}
```

[image]